How to mock this keyword in Jest test cases
My JS script has something like this:
 window.object_name = {
       //defined function
       testFunction: function(arg1,arg2){
    
       }
   
       testFunction_2 : function(){
      
          //calling testFunction in anotherfunction using 'this' keyword
          this.testFunction();
       }

    }

Calling testFunction in anotherfunction using this keyword but while running test cases this does not have reference of testFunction.
Tried to mock this keyword or redefining does not work.

Have you tried to reference to the window instead?

Don't - test behaviour, not implementation.

Getting error ● test cases for modulepack › testing
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'testFunction')


How did you call it? It should be window.object_name.testFunction_2()

But is there any way that i can mock or pass reference to 'this' keyword

@keerthi testFunction_2.call(testThisObject)

@DustInComp does nt work, can you please tell me if i need to use testFunction_2.call(window.Object_name) in between test cases

If you want this in testFunction_2 to refer to object_name, you should call it in any of these ways:
// direct property access assigns the object left of the . to `this`
object_name.testFunction_2()

const { testFunction_2 } = object_name
// without property access, `this` defaults to globalThis (the window object)
testFunction_2() // fails with 'this.testFunction is not a function'

// call or apply
testFunction_2.call(object_name)
testFunction_2.apply(object_name)

// bind `this`
const testFnBound = testFunction_2.bind(object_name)
testFnBound()

